# View listing element by date, exception for the first one

Tags: 8, views

I have a view which list a content type order by date.
I just want to add a simple condition : the first element of the list must the one with `ID = X`, even if it was created long time ago.
How can i do that ?

Comment: Maybe add a new field called pinned and set view sorted by pinned field ?

Comment: Nodes have a field that you could use here: "Sticky at the top of lists"

Comment: @sonfd , missed that , but if there are multiple nodes with sticky field it can not used as sort field

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it's no different than any other field on a content entity.

Comment: For a new field he can set the value as 1 for only that node , which makes it unique and can be used for sorting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two sort criteria, the first one on that ID and the second on the date.

Please note that the "ID" must have the same value for all other nodes except the first to make this works.

So probably it will be necessary to use an extra field - boolean, or integer, depending how many nodes you want to fine control.

If you don't have a lot of content to order in that view you otherwise may consider Entityqueue or DraggableViews.

Comment: Yes i add a new boolean field and made 2 order by. Simple !